# Azure App Service - run custom executable

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a .NET Core 2.2 Web Application and one functionality within this solution is to call a 3'rd party .exe to do some work

```
`ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(path_to_custom_exe_file, command_here)`
```

Is it possible to do this in Azure App Service or I should look at another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could call executable file in Azure web as long as your exe file no GUI.

I call a cmd file with below code:

```
 var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {

            FileName = @"D:\home\test.cmd",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

        var streamReader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream);



        ViewData["Message"] = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); ;

        return View();
```

[image]

[image]